# How to insert data to the next row in datagridview using c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Good day!

Please help me on my concern. I have a code here which allows to add rows to the datagridview I created named dgvSchedule. I want to transfer data from the other datagridview dgvCalendar by double clicking the data in the cell. My problem is I can only add data on the first row in dgvSchedule and the next rows are empty.

I have attached screenshot also of my application.

Thank you.

```
private void dgvCalendar_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbTimeSched.Text != "")
    {
        string yearnow = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        int year = Convert.ToInt32(yearnow);
        int rowIndex = dgvCalendar.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        int colIndex = dgvCalendar.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        if (dgvCalendar.Columns[colIndex].HeaderText != "SUN")
        {
            string Daynum = dgvCalendar.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].Value.ToString();
            int dayNum = Convert.ToInt32(Daynum);
            int num = DateTime.Parse("" + selectMonths.Text + year).Month;
            DateTime dateSelected = new DateTime(year, num, dayNum);
            dgvSchedule.Rows.Add();
            dgvSchedule.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = lblIDNum.Text;
            dgvSchedule.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = cmbTimeSched.Text;
            dgvSchedule.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = dgvCalendar.Columns[colIndex].HeaderText.ToString();
            dgvSchedule.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = dateSelected.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        }
        else
        { MessageBox.Show("You selected a date that is on SUNDAY!"); }                                  
    }
    else
    { MessageBox.Show("PLEASE SELECT TIME SCHEDULE FIRST!"); }
}
```

MyApplication:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because you are specifically saying to fill the record at Row[0] in dgvSchedule table.

```
 int count=dgvSchedule.Rows.Count;
 dgvSchedule.Rows[count+1].Cells[0].Value = lblIDNum.Text;
 dgvSchedule.Rows[count+1].Cells[1].Value = cmbTimeSched.Text;
 dgvSchedule.Rows[count+1].Cells[2].Value=
         dgvCalendar.Columns[colIndex].HeaderText.ToString();
 dgvSchedule.Rows[count+1].Cells[3].Value = dateSelected.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes. I am aware of that. I already tried using counter and loop but I will get an error  "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index". I think the row must start with 0 value. Do you have other suggestion?

Comment: Can't you use data set.Get the results to a data set and then fill the grid with the data set.before filling the grid have to refresh.

Comment: Thank you again for your response. I think I understand your idea on what to do but I don't know how to turn it into a code. Sorry I'm just a newbie. I guess I'll use like DataSet dgvTemporary = new DataSet(), like this?

Answer (score 0):

My other suggestion is you can use dataset to fill the grid.

```
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

                //remove all the rows of table
                while (dgvSchedule.Rows.Count > 1)
                {
                    dgvSchedule.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
                }

                //fill the table with updated records 
                cnn.Open();
                MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter("query for fetch the results from data base which you need to fill in the table", cnn);
                adp.Fill(dt1);
                dgvSchedule.DataSource = dt1;
                adp.Dispose();
                cnn.Close();
```

Comment: This is great. I'll have to try this first. So everytime I double click on the dgvCalendar I should store it first to the database and then fetch what's in the database and display it to the dgvSchedule. Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes.There is a performance issue.but if there is less data set thats ok.